# Elastic package in R: Sort for version > v5...not working

Tags: r, elasticsearch

Using elastic version V5.1
I'm trying to use the example of index shakespeare.
Tried:

```
   Search(index="shakespeare", type="act",  sort = '{"_source": ["speaker:desc"] }', size = 5)
```

and

```
 Search(index="shakespeare",body = '{"_source": ["play_name", "speaker", "text_entry"] }', 
   sort='{"_source": ["text_entry" : {"order" : "desc"}] }' ,q="york", size = 5)
```

But not getting the right results.
Can someone help me with the correct syntax for sort for version V5 above.
Thanks.

Comment: what's the expected result and what are you getting wrong?

Comment: working on a fix, will provide eg soon

Comment: thanks Scott...hope to get examples soon for sort

Answer (score 1):

Okay, fix pushed.

Reinstall like `devtools::install_github("ropensci/elastic")`

Problem is explained here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html

So to allow using sort on a field, need to enable `fielddata` on that field. so for the example above, do

```
library(elastic)
connect()
mapping_create("shakespeare", "act", update_all_types = TRUE, body = '{
  "properties": {
    "speaker": { 
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}')
res <- Search("shakespeare", "act", body = '{"sort":[{"speaker":{"order" : "desc"}}]}')
vapply(res$hits$hits, "[[", "", c("_source", "speaker"))
#> [1] "ARCHBISHOP OF YORK" "VERNON"             "PLANTAGENET"        "PETO"               "KING HENRY IV"     
#> [6] "HOTSPUR"            "FALSTAFF"           "CHARLES"            ""
```

does that work for you?

Comment: Okay...If I want to query like q="york" and set size = 5 how do I get the results sorted...currently seeing only one

Comment: currently seeing only one what?